# Why cannot android studio 2.1.3 import android.graphics.BitmapFactory?

Tags: android, bitmap, bitmapfactory

I'm learning Android using Android Studio 2.1.3, and want to use BitmapFactory to decode Bitmap. But when I import android.graphics.BitmapFactory , the import sentense is gray, and the hint box has no BitmapFactory in it, like this:
[image]

you see,there are only Bitmap,BitmapRegionDecoder,BitmapShader in it. 
Why was that?

How can I import BitmapFactory?
Anyone can give me a hand? Please, thank you sincerely.

Comment: `BitmapFactory` is in `android.graphics`, after importing, try to rebuild your project.

Comment: `BitmapFactory` is added in API level 1. Please make sure the SDK is configured correctly.

Comment: When creating this project , I choosed the `minSDKVersion 15`. Is that the reason?

Comment: Now , I have changed the minSDKVersion to 12 , but I still cannot `import android.graphics.BitmapFactory`